# libzmq.dll FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, zeromq

tl;dr Q. "how do we successfully deploy [unmanaged library] libzmq to load dynamically to support 'ZeroMQ CLR namespace' being used in a C# program?"

C# code with NuGet pkg ZeroMQ 4.1.0.17 (Runtime version v4.0.30319; Version 4.1.0.42169) installed.  Works just fine running in the Visual Studio workspace but when deployed with the .exe in the same directory as the ZeroMQ.dll and with an amd64 subdirectory containing both libzmq.dll and libsodium.dll -- and even with copies of both those copied up into the same exec directory as program and ZeroMQ.dll -- we get:

`Connect System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ZeroMQ.lib.zmq' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: UnmanagedLibrary[libzmq] Unable to load library "libzmq" from "C:\Windows\TEMP\libzmq.dll". Inspect Trace output for details. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ZeroMQ.lib.Platform.Win32.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(String libraryName)
   at ZeroMQ.lib.zmq..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ZeroMQ.ZContext..ctor()
   at Core.Adapter.ZeroMQ.ZeroMQMessagingService.Connect(String connection_string) in \ZeroMQMessagingService.cs:line 201`

Note that is says it is looking in C:\Windows\TEMP but maybe that is only the last place in a chain.

We're getting this after upgrading to ZeroMQ 4.1.0.21 and failing to load the libzmq.dll as an "embedded resource", so we removed .21 completely and returned to .17.  It had been working fine in .17 before we upgraded to .21.

Copy If Newer is checked on the amd64\libzmq.dll and libsodium.dll and, yes, this is an x64 build attempting to run on an x64 machine.  The failing host is 2012 Server running .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be very simple.  We are moving to a new machine still being configured and installing the C++ 2010 redistributable solved the problem for us.

Comment: Yeah... On Windows it is the MSVC2010 redist. On GNU/Linux it is GCC48.

Comment: I have the same issue with the 2010 redists. Under Visual Studio 2015, my zeromq code runs correctly with IIS Express but when I publish it to IIS, the server throws exceptions saying it can't find libzmq.dll in all the places it exists including c:\windows\system32

Comment: @wilsotc    Just guessing by extrapolation that your IIS machine will need the redists for 2015, then?

Comment: We were trying to run our code that uses ZeroMQ v4.1.0.31 on a W10 machine and it failed with the same error. For us, installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable did the trick! (we had to install both versions x86 and x64) - thanks!

Comment: For me, installing Microsoft Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable both x86 and x64 makes my C# program with libzmq.dll working on Windows Server 2008 R2. This is 2020. While I tried MSCV2010 redist beforehand it does not help.